# Rails associations and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a few models set up as Company and Employee. A company has many employees and a company should obviously be able to manage their employees.

What is the best approach to controller routing here? When a company want's to add a new employee should I route to the companies controller or to the employees controller?

For e.g. I could route to `companies/:id/edit` and then use a form with nested attributes to add employees. I could also just route to `employees/new`, or I could even use a nested resource and route to `companies/:id/employees/new`.

What do you think?

By the way I'm using `STI`, so `Company < User` and `Employee < User`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good question. Here is what I think of the three options:

1. Routing to `companies/:id/edit` is unacceptable. Although you do edit a company by adding employees it is not meant for this purpose. This route should be used in order to edit company fields like company name, location etc.
2. Routing to employees/new is a good option, but not the one I would go on.
3. This is the best option in my opinion. In your case nested resources are created only in the context of their parent resource, so every aspect of you application should follow this. This includes the url for creating these nested resources, and the creation method itself which should be done through `@company.employees.create!(params[:employee])` and not by `Employee.create...`

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe it's not the best, but it's convenient, easy understand, and follow the rails way. You should use nested routes:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :employees
end
```

Now you will have some routes like this:

```
company_employees    GET    /companies/:company_id/employees(.:format)          employees#index
                     POST   /companies/:company_id/employees(.:format)          employees#create
new_company_employee GET    /companies/:company_id/employees/new(.:format)      employees#new
```

So, When you create a new employee, you know which company that employee belongs to thanks to `:company_id`. All codes for create new employee, update, destroy... of course, will be put in `EmployeesController`. Then you need to build a nested form for create new employees belong to one company.

If you want create, edit, update... company? Just create new resources for it:

`resources :company`

So, you can edit company, as in your question writen, through path: `companies/:id/edit`.

Comment: Thanks both. It seems you agree. However i can't seem to get the forms to work nicely. Since i'm using STI the 'form_for' seems to generate code that will post to UsersController instead of EmployeesController. I can get it to work, but shouldn't the form recognize the resource as an Employee, instead of the User superclass?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Just looked thru my code. At some point i added a method to my User model that broke the forms. All is working fine. Thanks for the help.